# How to implement Handlebars.registerHelper functions with require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js, require-handlebars

Until now I used to write both `Handlebars.registerHelper and templates` inside `html` file itself. Now I am trying to implement`require.js` into my application. I moved `helper functions`into `.js` file and kept all `templates`inside `html` file itself. I configure `require` like in the following way.

```
 requirejs.config({
   baseUrl: "lib/js",
   paths: {
     js: "../../js",
     handlebars:"handlebars-v1.1.2"
   },
   shim:{
     "handlebars":{
        deps:[],
        exports:"Handlebars"
     },
   }
 }

 requirejs(["js/desktopHelper.js"])
```

desktopHelper.js :

```
define(
  ["handlebars"],
  function(Handlebars){
    Handlebars.registerHelper("maxmizeFun", function(json,attributeName){return json[attributeName];});
  }
);
```

After open my app in browser with this configuration, I am not able to open `console(F12)` and not able to close `browser` also completely hangs my app.

Note:For testing, before I open app in browser, I open `console` and open application what I observe `desktopHelper.js` loaded but there is no code inside file. I don't know how it's happen like that.

where I did wrong.

can anyone help me.

Comment: This has probably got to do with your paths. Upon defining `baseUrl` property, it will be taken as the root path to use for all module lookups. Is your desktopHelper.js path correct? can you show us relevant directory structure?

Comment: yes, Even if it wrong it will through `404` error I am not getting any error.

Comment: remove the `.js` suffix `requirejs(["js/desktopHelper"])`.